# Regex Validation with 3 formats

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I need in jquery check if string has one of the 3 following formats

```
1234-1234-1234-1234
1234/1234/1234/1234
1234123412341234
```

Could you help out? How to do it?

Comment: `["1234-1234-1234-1234","1234/1234/1234/1234","1234123412341234].indexOf(str) > -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a back reference to make sure that the separator is the same. Use `(-|/|)` to match a dash, a slash or nothing, then use `\1` to match it where it repeats:

```
^\d{4}(-|/|)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}$
```

Demo:

```js
var s = '1111-2222-3333-4444';

var ok = /^\d{4}(-|\/|)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}$/.test(s);

// show result in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(ok);
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: You only need to escape the slash if you use the regular expression in a regular expression literal, it's not part of the expression itself.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I don't think that "more readable" is a fitting expression to describe a regular expression, rather "less unreadable". ;) Anyway, I think that the current one is slightly more to the point, and neither is better for readability.

Comment: but it doesn't cover the case where only numbers are entered without - or / , what to do?

Comment: @MR.GEWA What makes you think so?

Comment: Oh I am wrong, sorry, its working. All is OK. Thank you